# How to return an unpacked list in Python?

Tags: python, return, tuples, unpack

I'm trying to do something like this in python:

```
def f():
    b = ['c', 8]
    return 1, 2, b*, 3
```

Where I want `f` to return the tuple `(1, 2, 'c', 8, 3)`. I found a way to do this using `itertools` followed by `tuple`, but this is not very nice, and I was wondering whether there exists an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The unpacking operator `*` appears before the `b`, not after it.

```
return (1, 2, *b, 3)
#      ^      ^^   ^
```

However, this will only work on Python 3.5+ ([PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)), and also you need to add parenthesis to prevent SyntaxError. In the older versions, use `+` to concatenate the tuples:

```
return (1, 2) + tuple(b) + (3,)
```

You don't need the `tuple` call if `b` is already a tuple instead of a list:

```
def f():
    b = ('c', 8)
    return (1, 2) + b + (3,)
```

Comment: `def func(): list1 = [1,2,3]
     return *list1
`
is there's a way to achieve this

using `print(*list1)` is possible but I would like to return in formatted string or just normally

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh - see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Note the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37732122/4901005) explains how to unpack some values when returning them as part of a tuple that includes some other values.  What if you only want to return the unpacked list?  Following up on a comment above:

```
def func():
   list1 = [1,2,3]
   return *list1
```

This gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

The solution is to add parentheses `(` and `)` and a comma `,` after the return value, to tell Python that this unpacked list is part of a tuple:

```
def func():
   list1 = [1,2,3]
   return (*list1,)
```

Comment: Nice workaround!